# Customize HTML template color

Tags: html, css

I downloaded an HTML template from html5up.net which can be found [here](https://html5up.net/solid-state).

I wanted to customize it by changing the blue color to orange, so I changed the color in main.css, and it did change.

However, it looked like this:
[image]
Instead of this:[image]
I don't know how this works, but I want the entire shape to be changed; how can I do that?

Comment: by "by changing the Blue color in Orange" you mean, change the blue stripes to orange whilst keeping the red? or do you mean red instead of orange, and make everything red?

Comment: It says the website is unreachable

Comment: There is a before and after psuedo element on that selector that creates the skewed top and bottom border and colors it.

Comment: Go to the template, right click on the skewed section and open the inspector, then highlight the `::before` just above of the `inner` selector. Then look in your ***styles*** section of the inspector and you will see the styled pseudo property and its values.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the two parts above and below the part which you changed its color are SVGs. You can simply go to the HTML file, find those two SVG elements and change their `fill` attributes' values. An example of an SVG element is:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```